# Splitting by a character in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to split it by a single character. Here, I want to split it by the number of `'a'` in the string. If I follow the below code, I get the length as 4, but I want to find the word with len =1 and that character should be `'a'`.

For e.g here, i should get len=2 but i am getting it as 4.

```
string s = "I found an apple in a tree";
string[] arr = s.Split('a');
int len = arr.Length;
```

Is there a way to find len=2 ? The answer should be 2 not 4.

Comment: The problem lies in the definition of the term `word`. What is a word by your rules?

Comment: I edited it...'I', 'found','an' are words..

Comment: I read over your question a few times but don't understand what your are trying to count when you say the length of the array should be 2.

Answer (score 3):

If I've undersood correctly you can include the spaces when splitting.

```
s.Split(new string[] { " a " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to split the entire string by character `'a'` but excluding those `a` which are the part of any word. For that you can try with another overload of `Split` function

```
 string[] arr = s.Split(new string[] {" a "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Here you are splitting the string by `a` with both side of whitespace.

So basically your string is not split by character; *it is split by another string*.